# Qual a origem da expressão «escuro como o breu»?

Tags: expressões, português-europeu, origem-histórica

De vez em quando por terras do Norte da Lusitânia, ouço:

> Está escuro como o breu.

Sei que serve para enfatizar a escuridão, mas não sei como se terá originado.

Qual a origem da expressão?

Comment: Coloquei a tag de português-europeu porque não sei se se usa no Brasil.

Comment: usamos no Brasil. Pelo menos no Sul do Brasil. Falamos algo como: *está um breu só!*

Comment: No sudeste do Brasil, eu ouço e falo "escuro como breu", sem o artigo.  Mas, também, usar o artigo ou não faz pouca diferença quando se fala pois  mal se percebe a sua presença ou ausência.

Comment: Além da construção comparativa "Escuro como breu", já ouvi "Está um breu!" como o @Peixoto disse, ou ainda "Que breu!".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sim, *breu* é usado no Brasil também, com o sentido de "escuridão total" ou "escuridão extrema".

Em seu sentido original, [breu](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breu_(betume)) é uma resina negra viscosa conhecida também como "piche" ou "betume". A expressão "escuro feito breu" veio duma comparação como "escuro feito piche" ou "escuro feito petróleo".

A palavra vem do francês ["brai"](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/brai/10906), derivado de sua forma verbal ["brayer"](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/brayer/11038) (cobrir com piche, pichar), que entrou no vocabulário espanhol como os verbos ["brear"](http://dle.rae.es/?id=64gO4IR|64gUkPI) e ["embrear"](http://dle.rae.es/?id=EgKxWMg) (untar com breu), e como o nome ["brea"](http://dle.rae.es/?id=64ZHQN6) (breu).

Na imagem, uma foto do poço de piche de Los Angeles chamado *[La Brea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Brea_Tar_Pits) (O Breu)*, como exemplo do uso original da palavra (ainda que noutra língua).

[image: La Brea]

Comment: Muito interessante, será sinonimo de alcatrão também?

Comment: Não conheço do assunto, mas o alcance semântico desses termos não é bem específico e muitas vezes se intersecciona uns aos outros. O [Michaelis](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/breu/) e o [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/breu) dizem que breu pode ser um derivado de alcatrão ou um tipo de betume. A Wikipedia diz que breu pode ser um [betume](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breu_(betume)) se derivado de petróleo ou uma [resina](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breu_(burser%C3%A1ceas)) se de origem vegetal.

Comment: Conheço o bairro de La Brea mas desconhecia a origem do nome.

Comment: @Centaurus. Sim, o poço de piche fica próximo a esse bairro (que, se não me engano, é perto de Hollywood). Segundo a Wikipédia, há outro poço de piche, em Trindade e Tobago, com o mesmo nome. Nos dicionários que vi, não consta que "brea" seja usado para se referir à cor negra ou à falta de luz; isso parece ser uma inovação do português.

Comment: Olha que curioso. O meu pai, matuto e roceiro de Campinas SP, fala "breu" para se referir ao escuro total. Ele é de um tempo que a luz elétrica era ausente e ele saia de madruga para caçar na mata. Tive a experiência de estar no "breu" de olhos abertos. É uma experiência profunda.